Unity Netcode (Multiplayer) client is not owner of its player
I created a project and setup all the necessary stuff for multiplayer with netcode for gameobjects. But one thing that is not working is player movement for clients. It says that client is not owner of the player GO. It works perfectly fine for Host though.
I am using:
if (!IsOwner) return;

Does anybody experience this issue ? I am using unity version 2022.3.48f. I tried to create a new project again and set everything according to a unity official tutorial but still the same issue.

If host says is owner. Tada. Host owns.

No, because there is a Network manager class where is player prefab assigned and everytime client is joined into the session it should create a new player instance and the client should be owner of this player GO. And it is not working that way and that's why it doesn't make sense to me.

Then you arent doing that. If the host says it owns it. It owns it.  You would need to do detailed explanation of how this is setup

You can add the owner id as a parameter when instantiating the object using InstantiateAndSpawn.  You might also consider using HasAuthority rather than IsOwner.

I fixed it. I was using Network Transform which sets server as owner. I had to create my own class Client Network Transform where i set server authoritative to false.
